# JCE groups - problems with multiple permissions

Tags: joomla, permissions, media, joomla-content-editor

I have Joomla site using JCE. I use the JCE groups to create permissions for different users.

I have created few groups and every group is permitted to control one media directory.

I have combined a specific user to two different groups assuming that this user will have the ability to access two different media directories.

But the user can access only one directory -- the first one I have assigned.

Can anybody help me to fix this problem?

What should I do in order to give a specific user access to different directories?

Comment: how have you 'combined' the user to two different groups?

Comment: i have the option in jce groups to choose the user or users. These users will have all permissions were given to this group including the the media directory.

in case i would like to give specific user a permission to different media directories so I have to choose this user in two different groups

Comment: While [joomla.se] Stack Exchange did not exist back when this questions was posted, please post all Joomla questions there to gain the attention of a dedicated audience with a more intimate knowledge of the CMS and its extensions. Since there are no answers,  this may be a good page to migrate there.